# How to allow mouse centering while switching tabs if mouse is moving?

Tags: windows-10

The command `ALT`+`ESC` switches to the next window in windows-10. I have the mouse set to center on the newly focused window (I followed [this tutorial](https://winaero.com/blog/turn-on-xmouse-active-window-tracking-focus-follows-mouse-pointer-feature-in-windows-8-1-windows-8-and-windows-7/) to achieve the mouse centering behavior). However if I am moving the mouse and I hit `ALT`+`ESC` it will change focus, but not move the mouse to that window. Is there anyway to circumvent or fix this bug?

I am also using the following AutoHotkey to set Capslock to `ALT`+`ESC`:

```
Capslock::Send,{AltDown}{Esc}{AltUp}
```

My use case is playing two action games at once. (Why? Because why not?) One on each monitor. When switching between them I use 'ALT'+'ESC'. The problem is if I am moving the mouse when I do this it wont switch, and inevitably this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following AutoHotkey script has solved my problem:

```
Capslock::
Send,{AltDown}{Esc}{AltUp}
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
MouseMove, Width / 2, Height / 2, 0
Return
```

In addition to the command, we are also setting the position of the mouse. This does not fix the issue. Rather, this is a work around.